# Confusion about simulation of projective measurements

Tags: quantum-algorithms

[The authors present an algorithm to obtain a state that is proportional to the solution of a system of linear equations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.10549). The algorithm works by evolving with a hamiltonian $H(s+ \delta)$ on the ground state of a nearby hamiltonian $H(s)$, which it is claimed essentially simulates a projective measurement on the ground state of $H(s+ \delta)$. However, I don't see how this works exactly. It is also said by one of the authors in [this video](https://youtu.be/JlIyLNndHaU?si=BGSpahgTBC0_ktlF) (timestamp 46:00). Could someone elaborate on this ?